# Direct2d offscreen rendering buggy?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, direct2d

I'm trying to render a bitmap using an offscreen bitmaprendertarget and then draw that on the screen. It works just fine but when I try to render seperate bitmaps on it, it's like the render doesn't work and it only clips the original picture.

Here's what it looks like: http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/7991/clipped.png

I'm using a compatiblerendertarget with the hwndrendertarget. Funny thing is, when I render them using the onscreen hwndrendertarget, they come out just fine.

Like this: http://img141.imageshack.us/img141/4825/workingj.png

I'm using CopyFromRendertarget to get the bitmap out of the Rendertarget, as the GetBitmap doesn't work for me with the Bitmaprendertarget for some reason. This is on Visual studio 2010 C++.

Anyone know what's going on here?

---- EDIT ----

An interesting thing to note: I tried putting clear after getting the bitmap and then doing EndDraw, but then it only gets the first bitmap, and the other bitmaps won't get drawn at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experimenting some stuff and noticed that I don't need to put EndDraw at all to the bitmaprendertarget in order for it to get the bitmaps needed. I can call EndDraw on it when I'm done using the offscreen RT and it works just fine.

Comment: Actually, my custom function that called EndDraw was outdated and it only called it for the hwndrendertarget, so it never called the enddraw for the bitmaprendertarget. So when I fixed that, it worked flawlessly.